# Cannot bind an Observable Collection to an Attached Property on an UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I want to bind an ObservableCollection of custom type (BoundItem) to a view.

I am using it this way :

```
<v:MyUserControlBase x:Class="My.Views.MyView"
         (...)
         h:FrameworkElementDropBehavior.MyItems="{Binding Attachments}">
```

Attachments is defined in the ViewModel as :

```
public ObservableCollection<BoundItem> Attachments 
{ 
   get { return _Attachments; } 
   set { _Attachments = value; } 
}
```

My view is an actual DependencyObject since when I do in the code behind of the view the following piece of code:

```
MessageBox.Show((this as DependencyObject).ToString());
```

it shows "True".

I defined my Dependency Property that way:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<BoundItem>), typeof(MyView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
    public static string GetMyItems(DependencyObject element)
    {
        if (element == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("MyItems");
        return (ObservableCollection<BoundItem>)element.GetValue(MyItemsProperty);
    }
    public static void SetMyItems(DependencyObject element, ObservableCollection<BoundItem> value)
    {
        if (element == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("MyItems");
        element.SetValue(MyItemsProperty, value);
    }
```

The error that occurs is:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SetMyItems' property of type 'MyView'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Thanks for you help :) .x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with your property registration. Instead of owner type `MyView` it should be `FrameworkElementDropBehavior` i,e the class where you are defining your property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemsProperty =
     DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyItems", 
                                        typeof(ObservableCollection<BoundItem>), 
                                        typeof(FrameworkElementDropBehavior), 
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, SetMyItems 2nd argument should be of type ObservableCollection and GetMyItems should have the return type ObservableCollection.

Comment: Oops, that's fixed but the error still occurs. Thanks (: